# Uploading a .csv to a NoSQL cluster - batch faster than consumer/producer

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was tasked with making a program that uploads a .csv to a NoSQL cluster. The files are larger (typically 2-17GB). My program works in batch mode and can process a 17GB file in 6 hours.

I decided to make a consumer-producer multithreading structure. This caused it to be significantly slower. I want to know why the producer-consumer construct was slower than a batch produce, batch consume method.

The batch looks like this:

```
int count = 0;
        //
        Row r;

        while ((r = rm.getNextRow()) != null)
        {
            RowQueue.Enqueue(r);
            while (RowQueue.Count <= ROWMAX)
            {
                if ((r = rm.getNextRow()) != null)
                    RowQueue.Enqueue(r);
                else
                    break;
            } //

            int uniqueIdentifer = -1;
            if (count > 1000)
            {
                PrintAndSavePosition(count, rm, positionQueue, true);
                count = 0;
            }
            //give it some extra room to be safe
            while (RowQueue.Count != 0)
            {
                r = RowQueue.Dequeue();
                while (uniqueIdentifer == -1)
                {
                    uniqueIdentifer = nsqw.tryPut(r);
                    if (uniqueIdentifer == -1)
                        Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
                count++;
            }

            positionQueue.Add(new Tuple<int, long>(uniqueIdentifer, rm.Position));
         }
```

As compared to

```
public void produceLoop(){
            while (true)
            {

                while (RowQueue.Count <= ROWMAX && (r = rm.getNextRow()) != null){
                    RowQueue.Enqueue(r);
                }

            } 
 }

public void consumeLoop(){
     while(true){
     while (RowQueue.Count != 0)
            {
                RowQueue.TryDequeue(out r);
                while (uniqueIdentifer == -1)
                {
                    uniqueIdentifer = nsqw.tryPut(r);
                    if (uniqueIdentifer == -1)
                        Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
                count++;
            }

            positionQueue.Add(new Tuple<int, long>(uniqueIdentifer, rm.Position));
         }
 }


}
```

The bottom half are infinite loops for a speed test.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert in cluster operations, so I'll review the parts I do know.

**Single-letter variable names**

These are a big no-no unless the only thing you're worried about is not being fireable. Any maintenance programmer looking in the middle of a chunk of code is not going to be happy jumping back and forwards to definitions to work out what on earth `r` is when you could just as easily have written `row`.

**var**

You should use `var` when the right hand side of an assignment makes the type obvious. e.g.

`int uniqueIdentifier = 1;`

should be

`var uniqueIdentifier = 1;`

This is recommended because if you decide to change the type (e.g. to a GUID), you only have to change it in one place.

**Style**

In C# the general naming guideline for methods is to use PascalCase. This is, of course, optional (as with any point on style), but recommended to make code easier to read for another programmer.